# Problems with the way navigation and content are overlapping

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, overlapping

Thanks in advance.

I have a navigation bar that slides out when you hover over it, making overlap with the content on the rest of the page.  This works perfectly with most of it, but when I put a flash or jquery element on-screen, said elements are presented over the navigation.

I know that one way to fix this would be to put the navigation bar html below the others, but an alternative way would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without specific code samples (or a link to a demo page) it will be almost impossible to trouble-shoot. However, there's some general things to know:

- Problems with jQuery or Flash elements will often have different independent solutions.
- JavaScript UI elements can be appended to virtually any part of the document, so changing HTML order won't likely help anyhow

and the actual suggestion:

- The z-index CSS property is an obvious first place to look to try to solve the problem. You might need to apply a higher z-index to the element you want "on top". (be careful, some JS will dynamically change z-indexes). Z-index is a fickle beast and may not do anything for you.

Comment: Sometimes I worry about posting an answer that doesn't contain a fully fleshed out code-based solution; but then sometimes these kinds of answers work out, which makes me glad. ;-)